# Dependency of one element on another using XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-parsing, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I need to check that if `imagetype` = `I` then `docext` should only be `TIFF/tiff` and if `imagetype` = `N` then `docext` should be `PDF/pdf`. Else the validation should fail.  I am writing a XSD for this and do not know how to implement this constraint.   Currently I am using XSD 1.0.

```
<xs:element name="docext" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
  <xs:simpleType>                       
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="((T|t)(I|i)(F|f)(F|f))|((P|p)(D|d)(F|f))" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="imagetype" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="N" />
        <xs:enumeration value="I" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XSD 1.0 cannot meet your requirements as stated.

Your options include either of the following:

1. **Redesign your XML.**  If possible, this is the better option.  Type
   information is typically better conveyed via element names than
   element values; such a design can often obviate the need for
   dependency constraints beyond what can be expressed via basic
   content model requirements.
2. **Use XSD 1.1 assertions.**  You can use XPath to specify constraints at
   the point of a common ancestor to `docext` and `imagetype`.  You'll
   need to consider more of your XSD than shown if you have to go this route.